# How do I find the radius and interval of convergence for the power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

> Find the radius and interval of convergence for the power series $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}\left( \frac{n!}{2 \times 5 \times 8 \times \ldots\times(3n+2)} \right)^3x^{5n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $a_n=\left(\frac{n!}{2 \times 5 \times 8 \times \cdots\times(3n+2)}\right)^3$ then
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{3n+5}\right)^3=\frac{1}{27}.$$
Hence, by the [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), the radius of convergence of the power series
$$z\to\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$
is $R=27$.

Then, what is the radius of convergence of the power series
$$x\to\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{5n}\quad ?$$

As regards the product $2 \times 5 \times 8 \times \cdots \times (3n+2)$ see also $f_2(n)$ in [closed-form expressions for product of 3n+k where k = 1 or 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173603/closed-form-expressions-for-product-of-3nk-where-k-1-or-2)
You need the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to determine the exact interval of convergence.

Comment: yes, thank you !I have one question tho.The only thing that bothers me is what do I do with the 2x5x8....?

Comment: Have you tried to compute the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?